# Python: item.method() and function(item)

Tags: python, function, logic

What is the logic for picking some methods to be prefixed with the items they are used with, but some are functions that need items as the arguments? 
For example:

```
    L=[1,4,3]    
    print len(L)  #function(item)  
    L.sort()  #item.method()
```

I thought maybe the functions that modify the item need to be prefixed while the ones that return information about the item use it as an argument, but I'm not too sure.

Edit:

What I'm trying to ask is why does python not have **L.len()**? What is the difference between the nature of the two kinds of functions? Or was it randomly chosen that some operations will be methods while some will be functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the principles behind Python is [*There is Only One Way to Do It*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TOOWTDI). In particular, to get the length of a sequence (array / tuple / xrange...), you always use `len`, regardless of the sequence type.

However, sorting is not supporting on all of those sequence types. This makes it more suitable to being a method.

```
a = [0,1,2]
b = (0,1,2)
c = xrange(3)
d = "abc"

print len(a), len(b), len(c), len(d) # Ok

a.sort() # Ok
b.sort() # AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
c.sort() # AttributeError: 'xrange' object has no attribute 'sort'
d.sort() # AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess this makes sense. I'm looking for something more general,  not limited to the example I put in the question.

Comment: Oh k, I think I got it: is this right: operations that require the same inner level coding for any data type are function(item) but the ones that are specific to the data type are item.method(), right?

Answer (score 1):

Something that may help you understand a bit better: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

What you describe as `item.function()` is actually a method, which is defined by the class that said `item` belongs to. You need to form a comprehensive understanding of `function`, `class`, `object`, `method` and maybe more in Python.

Just conceptually speaking, when you call `L.sort()`, the `sort()` method of type/class `list` actually accepts an argument usually by convention called `self` that represents the object/instance of the type/class `list`, in this case `L`. And `sort` just like a standalone `sorted` function but just applies the sorting logic to `L` it**self**. Comparatively, `sorted` function would require an iterable (a `list`, for example), to be its required argument in order to function.

Code example:

```
my_list = [2, 1, 3]

# .sort() is a list method that applies the sorting logic to a
# specific instance of list, in this case, my_list
my_list.sort()

# sorted is a built-in function that's more generic which can be
# used on any iterable of Python, including list type
sorted(my_list)
```

Comment: Oops... I'll change that to method. I think I need to make my question clearer.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `len(L)` is a special case, as even though it's a function, it's basically syntax sugar for a method call, specifically it does something like `return L.__len__()`

Comment: @Emisor yes. I was going to mention that in the answer, however I think it may overwhelm OP. That's why I only provided very high-level concept of this matter.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bigger difference between methods and functions than just their syntax.

```
def foo():
    print "function!"

class ExampleClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "method!"
```

In this example, i defined a function `foo` and a class `ExampleClass` with 1 method, `foo`.
Let's try to use them:

```
>>> foo()
function!
>>> e = ExampleClass()
>>> e.foo()
method!
>>> l = [3,4,5]
>>> l.foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    l.foo()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>>
```

Even though both have the same name, Python knows that if you do foo(), your calling a function, so it'll check if there's any function defined with that name.

And if you do a.foo(), it knows you're calling a method, so it'll check if there's a method `foo` defined for objects of the type `a` has, and if there is, it will call it. In the last example, we try that with a list and it gives us an error because lists don't have a `foo` method defined.